# Angular 2 - Как пробросить событие через цепочку родительских компонентов к главному

Tags: angular2

Интересуюсь как правильно передать событие, к примеру, от **Кнопки** до Главной **формы**, если они расположены в такой последовательности:

```
 Главная форма->Компонент 1->Компонент 2->...->Кнопка
```

Пока что я решаю эту проблему пробросом события из каждого вложенного компонента. Может есть более быстрый и удобный способ?

Comment: Нужно понять контекст - поподробней что за компоненты, что делает кнопка. Скорее всего если вам надо делать более общие события с каждым уровнем выше...

Answer (score 2):

Если хочется именно по цепочке через всех то надо городить кучу @Output() параметров по одному на каждый вложенный компонент, как-то так:

```
<app-main>
    <app-cmp1 (myEvent)="onMyEvent($event)">
        <app-cmp2 (myEvent)="onMyEvent($event)">
            <app-cmp3 (myEvent)="onMyEvent($event)">
                <button (click)="sendMyEventUp()">
                </button>
            </app-cmp3>
        </app-cmp2>
    </app-cmp1>
</app-main>
```

и соответственно в каждом компоненте обработчик события передает событие выше.

А если в промежуточных компонентах это событие не нужно, то проще сделать сервис, объявить в нем точно такой же EventEmitter, инжектить сервис в мейн и компонент с кнопкой, и так же по нажатию вызывать emit и получать событие сразу в мейне.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать сервис. Типа такого.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class FiltersHandlerService {
    private filters: any = {};
    private changeFilters = new Subject<boolean>();
    changeFilters$ = this.changeFilters.asObservable();

    private sportFilters = new Subject<boolean>();
    sportFilters$ = this.sportFilters.asObservable();

    handleValue(filter: any, type?:string) {
        for (let i in filter) {
            this.filters[i] = filter[i];
        }

        if (type == 'sport') {
            this.sportFilters.next(this.filters);
            return;
        }

        this.changeFilters.next(this.filters);
    }
}
```

Затем из нужного компонента вызываешь через сервис событие.

```
this.FiltersHandlerService.handleValue({your_value})
```

И в нужном компоненте подписываешься на него.

```
this.FiltersHandlerService.changeFilters$.subscribe({your_handler});
```

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, костыль какой-то, но можно триггерить событие на dom-элементе. Тогда сработает всплытие и его будет можно обработать на любомродительском элементе.

Есть подозрение, что ангуляр предоставляет какую-то аналогичную функциональность, но точно не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

в child компонент в конструктор пробросить через DI родительский компонент
Пример:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {RootComponent} from './root.component.ts';

@Component({selector: 'child', templateUrl: './child.component.html'})
export class ChildComponent {
    constructor(protected rootComponent: RootComponent) {
    }

    click() {
        // Выполняем действия и передаем в аргумент функции RootComponent-а,
        // если есть необходимость
        // В вашем случае это компонент формы
        this.rootComponent.formEvent()
    }
}
```